# Symfony2 Optional parameter in routing has no value

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I am struggling with this detail while defining a route in Symfony2

Mi routing:

```
blog:
path: /blog/{page}
defaults: { _controller: ManualRouteBundle:Blog:show, page: 33 }
```

My controller:

```
<?php
namespace Manual\RouteBundle\Controller ;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class BlogController extends Controller{
    public function showAction($page){

        return $this->render('ManualRouteBundle:Blog:show.html.twig') ;
    }
}
```

My view:

```
Blog # {{page}}
```

When I try to access with this address

```
http://test/web/blog
```

instead of

```
http://test/web/blog/1
```

I get this error

```
 Variable "page" does not exist in ManualRouteBundle:Blog:show.html.twig at line 1
500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime
```

Isn't page value supposed to be 33?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer on #symfony, I have to pass the variable to the view.

```
$this->render() like this: $this->render('show.html.twig', array('page' => $page));
```

Weird behavior imho.